# Car brush extendable jam(can't be retracted)

Tags: car

I have a a car brush that I use to clear snow on the windows during the Winter.

You can see one the that look similar in the following picture:

[image]

Both the bottoms can't be pressed down and so the brush stay in extended state.

How do you fix it so that we can retract it?

Answer (score 1):

Likely there's some road salt jamming the mechanism. You can try soaking the brush in hot water for some time, trying to wiggle the parts a bit, and press the buttons while wiggling.

Don't use oil to lubricate it, though, because some will wind up on the windows.